# profile not found with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I created a new application with spring boot 2.4.1

in my applicaiton.properties

spring.config.activate.on-profile=local

i have another file name: application-local.properties

```
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/invoice
spring.r2dbc.username=invoice_admin
spring.r2dbc.password=invoice
```

When i start applicaiton

```
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

Also i see

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a ConnectionFactory: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded database could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable R2DBC Connection URL


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add

```
spring.profiles.active=local
```

to your `application.properties`

Please note that you refer to this file as `applicaiton.properties` in your question, hence you should check the spelling in your project file.

You should explore the option of converting your application.properties to application.yml. Example application.yml:

```
server:
  error:
    include-message: always
    include-binding-errors: always
spring:
  profiles:
    active:
      - dev
  datasource:
    generate-unique-name: false
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
  jpa:
    properties:
      javax:
        persistence:
          validation:
            mode: none
  data:
    web:
      pageable:
        default-page-size: 10
        max-page-size: 100
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: prod
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: false
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: test
```

With multiple profiles, it is good practice (a necessity) to annotate your test classes like this:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```

A little trick to keep things away from your tests, is to annotate e.g. beans with:

```
@Profile("!test")
```

Comment: I have misunderstood  spring.config.activate.on-profile utility with old key: spring.profiles.active that work........ not a fan of yml

Answer (score 0):

Try this out
**In your pom.xml** (inside `<project></project>` tag)

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>local</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**In your** `application.properties` **file**

```
spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@
```